# Is there a workaround to bring the method "present" in a UIimageView class?

Tags: swift4

I created a class for my Logo UIimageView which is on every ViewController in my app. Now I want to create a tapGesture to jump back to the Home ViewController when it is tapped like Logos on Homepages back to index. How can I get the present method to work in the class UIimageView?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LogoImageView: UIImageView {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let TapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.imageTapped))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(TapGesture)
    }
    
    @objc func imageTapped()  {
        
        let mainStoryboad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        guard let destinationViewController = mainStoryboad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController else {
            return
        }
        
        present(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve got the solution for my problem. I added an extension to check the current ViewController to use the present method. Now I´m able to add every UIimageview this class and it brings me back to the root viewcontroller.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class LogoImageView: UIImageView {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let TapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self
            .imageTapped))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(TapGesture)
    }

    @objc func imageTapped()  {

        let mainStoryboad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        guard let destinationViewController = mainStoryboad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController else {
            return
        }

        guard let currentViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.topMostViewController() else {
            return
        }
        destinationViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .flipHorizontal
        currentViewController.present(destinationViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension UIWindow {

    func topMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        guard let rootViewController = self.rootViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        return topViewController(for: rootViewController)
    }

    func topViewController(for rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let rootViewController = rootViewController else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController else {
            return rootViewController
        }
        switch presentedViewController {
        case is UINavigationController:
            let navigationController = presentedViewController as! UINavigationController
            return topViewController(for: navigationController.viewControllers.last)
        case is UITabBarController:
            let tabBarController = presentedViewController as! UITabBarController
            return topViewController(for: tabBarController.selectedViewController)
        default:
            return topViewController(for: presentedViewController)
        }
    }

}
```